Unable to Install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 11 on Lenovo Ideapad 5i Pro
I have a Lenovo Ideapad 5i pro with the following specs:

CPU-Intel Core i7-13700H
GPU-NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3050 6GB GDDR6
Storage-1TB SSD M.2 2242 PCIe® 4.0x4 NVMe
Windows 11 preinstalled

I tried to boot Ubuntu 20.04 from a bootable USB stick, created by both using Rufus and balenaEtcher on subsequent attempts. As soon as I enter the boot manager, this thing comes and screen gets stuck:

Due to this error, I'm unable to even boot into Ubuntu. So, I went into my bios, and switched off Switchable Graphics and changed to UMA Graphics. After that, I was able to install Ubuntu 20.04.06. But, there were many problems:

No Wifi adapter detected (numerous attemptsfailed).
Poor Display Quality, Brightness Control Not Working, unknown display.
HDMI Port not working.
Nvidia Graphic Card not detected.( I tried to install Nvidia-smi and other drivers, still, nothing worked).

After this poor installation, I enabled switchable graphics mode and the system failed to dual boot because the screen got stuck with this error:

It should be noted that Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 24.04 run perfectly well without any of these errors. Only Ubuntu 20.04.06 gets this error. Also I am using VMware Virtual Machine Ubuntu 20.04. These are my questions:

Is my Windows installation causing this error?
Are Nvidia drivers causing a problem?
Should I add a new SSD?
Is the virtual machine causing errors?

I followed many such posts, but the main things is that I am unable to install correct Drivers in UMA Graphics Card Mode. Secondly I am unable to even boot into the installer normally.
I am an undergraduate student interested in pursuing robotics, so I need ROS 1 (Noetic) support that is only compatible with Ubuntu 20.04.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is the 2020-April release of Ubuntu; so it contains much older kernel stacks that later 22.04 & 24.04 will use; why are you trying to use the older 20.04 release that is in its final months of standard support; it reaches EOSS in April 2025; five years after its initial release don't forget.

given that v20.04 will become EOL next April and 22.04 runs well which will be supported until April '27, I think your choice is clear... Given questions in the past, I'd consider Nvidia the issue here.

I get that, but I have seen PCs with similar hardware runnning perfectly well, then where exactly is the issue? As I mentioned in the edited post, I need ROS Noetic.

You mention release; but no specifics as to what 20.04 ISO you used; as 20.04 ISOs exist with the 5.4, 5.8, 5.11, 5.13 & 5.15 kernels & you've not specified anything but release. If you're using 20.04.6 as you do refer to it once; that still leaves 5.4 & 5.15 kernels depending on which 20.04.6 ISO you attempted to use.

Ok so I went to advanced options for Ubuntu, and it showd kernel showed recovery options for some versions of 5.15
